# Email verification for registration in Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, spree, devise-confirmable

I want my users to verify their email addresses while logging in. By default Spree Commerce doesn't provide email verification. How can I make sure that users' email address is verified before he is able to make changes in the account?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do account verification? I want to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that a given user is who they say, that's something outside of Spree and you have to do it on your own, or with the help of a authentication gem.

If you want to check if a given user already has a Spree account, it seems like Spree does offer this, but you're right that it isn't used by default.  From their [documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html#default-checkout-steps) (emphasis is my own):

> Prior to beginning the checkout process, the customer will be prompted to create a new account or to login to their existing account. By default, there is also a “guest checkout” option which allows users to specify only their email address if they do not wish to create an account.
>
> Technically, the registration step is not an actual state in the Spree::Order state machine. The spree_auth_devise gem (an extension that comes with Spree by default) adds the check_registration before filter to the all actions of Spree::CheckoutController (except for obvious reasons the registration and update_registration actions), which redirects to a registration page unless one of the following is true:
>
> - Spree::Auth::Config[:registration_step] preference is not true
> - user is already logged in
> - the current order has an email address associated with it
>
> The configuration of the guest checkout option is done via Preferences. Spree will allow guest checkout by default. **Use the allow_guest_checkout preference to change the default setting.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problems. But hope this helps you...
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up